# Creating a module arguments page with a shorter URL

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm creating two pages with a custom the module. The first page makes an API call to create an XML object and then lists all objects. Each object contains 10 entries but i only display 3 of them. From here clicking on an object directs users to a module argument page.

Is there anyway for me to create an argument page that doesn't have 10 different entries in the URL?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  //general page
  $items['my_module'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module List',
    'description' => 'My module list Page',
    'page callback' => '_my_module_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
  //single event page
  $items['my_module/event/%/%/%/%/%/%/%/%/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_my_module_arguments',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10,11),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is concatenating arguments by a dilemma (something like -) and in callback function explode them simply by Php [Explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  //general page
  $items['my_module'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Module List',
    'description' => 'My module list Page',
    'page callback' => '_my_module_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
  //single event page
  $items['my_module/event/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_my_module_arguments',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function _my_module_arguments($args){
 $items = explode("-",$args); // you can use another dilemma instead -
  //$items[0] first arg
  //$items[1] second arg
}
```